# Update date field on a VF page once value was entered in one of the field

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have created a VF page which looks like the one below.

[image]

Once a user enter's `"Available Start Date"`, the `"Available End Date"` field should be populated by that date.

Not sure how to do that? Can this be done using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it either with javascript or with apex.
Here is an example with apex:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="setDate" action="{!setSecondDate}" reRender="date2"/>

<apex:inputField value="{!obj.date1__c}" onblur="setDate();"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!obj.date2__c}" id="date2"/>

public pageReference setSecondDate(){
    obj.date2__c = obj.date1__c;
    return null;
}
```

Or just using some javascript:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!obj.date1__c}" onblur="setSecondDate(this);"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!obj.date2__c}" id="date2"/>

<script>
    function setSecondDate(elem){
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.date2}').value = elem.value;
    }
</script>
```

Here is a nice example of [how to reference visualforce component using javascript](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_access.htm).